# UX Moderator Cards

Tags: discussion, design, community

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place.

If you're a ux.stackexchange moderator, would you be interested in having your own UX Stack Exchange contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out during your local meetups or conferences.

Below is a mockup:

(click on image to see full res version)

[image: ux.stackexchange.com moderator cards]

Of course Twitter ID/email/website are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, another URL etc.

<sub>Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.</sub>

Comment: Ooh, rounded corners. They look great! Cards would be awesome, but there's very few relevant meetups where I'm located.

Comment: Look at that subtle off-white coloring; the tasteful thickness of it... Oh my God, it even has a watermark.

Comment: Also something to note; we recently changed the FAQ site description to be more inclusive of roles: http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/940/is-our-faq-text-too-exclusive

Comment: It's tough to bring gadgets to this site - you always get comment on stuff you didn't realize: rounded corners, off-white colors, thickness, watermark and an outdated description. But I loved the T-shirt, the stickers (now on my PC) and the UX-notebook we got a few months ago. Hang in there, Anna, these users are hard to please.

Comment: @BennySkogberg Thanks. :) Myrddin's comment is actually a quote from the movie "American Psycho". It has a great scene about business cards.

Comment: @AnnaLear LOL. Yet a movie I didn't see, but it's on my list now. Along with my must-see Almodovar-movies.